# redirect all traffic to https://www. on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, symfony-1.4

I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

I would like to Redirect all traffic through to https no matter what the user puts into the url bar.

Because of the sessions it either needs to be Always NO-WWW or Always with WWW

Here is my current nginx config.

What change would I have to make to redirect everything till https?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/example-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/example-error.log;
  root /var/www/html/web;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
  }

  rewrite ^/backend\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
    location /admin {
    index admin content backend.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
  }

 location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /backend.php/$1 last;
  }

 location ~ "^(.+\.php)($|/)" {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    include        fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: Serverfault has the [most complete answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom), the idea is to match `server_name` to both WWW and NON-WWW and then `return 301 https//:...` for everything to another server.  In essence you need two server blocks.

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies. -- clear cookies no difference

Comment: I added an answer because it was too big for a comment.  See the note in the answer, `301` is rather dangerous for testing because the browser remembers it and will not issue another GET (or POST) to a URL for which it received a `301`.

Answer (score 0):

You need two server blocks, that is the best practice with `nginx`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate     mycert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key mycert.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    ... (all the locations, index and etecetras)
}
```

Note that you must use `listen 443 ssl` to [enable `ssl`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl).  Otherwise `nginx` would be completely happy in serving content over HTTP on port 443.

I do not see the SSL certificates or allowed protocols/ciphers in your question, therefore i added them in the answer just in case.

---

Note that `301` is remembered by browsers.  Once a browser sees a `301` it will redirect forever (or until you destroy its cache).  For debugging purposes it is better to use `302` and then change it to `301` in production.